# Sign Problem When Dealing With Quadratic Air Resistance and Gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, conventions, projectile, drag

While dealing with an object falling vertically, and subject to quadratic air resistance, an equation of motion that is often presented is 
\begin{equation*}
m\dot{v} =mg-cv^{2}
\end{equation*}
In this equation, down is treated as positive. Now, in my mind, it would seem that the directions you treat as positive and negative shouldn't matter. Therefore, I proceeded to try and solve the following equation of motion.
\begin{equation*}
m\dot{v} =-mg-cv^{2}
\end{equation*}
The only difference between this equation and the previous one is that I am now treating down as negative. Now, this is where the problems come. My first problem is that of the terminal velocity, denoted by
\begin{equation}
v_{ter}
\end{equation}
To find this in the context of the first equation, I can simply set the force equal to zero, and solve.
\begin{equation}
v_{ter} =\sqrt{\frac{mg}{c}}
\end{equation}
For the second equation, the result isn't so simple.
\begin{equation}
v_{ter} =\sqrt{-\frac{mg}{c}}
\end{equation}
Now here is where the problems begin. If I let myself use complex numbers, then I can write this as
\begin{equation}
v_{ter} =i\sqrt{\frac{mg}{c}}
\end{equation}
Now this is a little iffy. I am not very comfortable with the idea of having a speed that is complex. So that is my first question: Is it okay to have a complex speed?

Now comes the task of solving the equation of motion. I can rewrite it as
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{dt} =-g\left( 1+\frac{c}{mg} v^{2}\right)
\end{equation}
It can be seen that
\begin{equation}
v^{2}_{ter} =-\frac{mg}{c}
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{dt} =-g\left( 1-\frac{v^{2}}{v^{2}_{ter}}\right)
\end{equation}
Now I am going to define a new quantity. 
\begin{equation}
v_{T} =\sqrt{\frac{mg}{c}} =\frac{1}{i} v_{ter}
\end{equation}
The reason for doing this is so I can write the equation of motion as
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{dt} =-g\left( 1+\frac{v^{2}}{v^{2}_{T}}\right)
\end{equation}
The reason for defining this term is so that I can have a positive, rather than a negative, in order to compute the integral by trigonometric substitution using tangent, which is just the method I noticed first and thought would be easiest.

From the equation of motion I get
\begin{equation}
-gt=\int ^{v}_{v_{0}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{v^{\prime 2}}{v_{T}}} dv'=v_{T}\arctan\left(\frac{v}{v_{T}}\right) -v_{T}\arctan\left(\frac{v_{0}}{v_{T}}\right)
\end{equation}
where v' is just the dummy variable. If I assume that the object started from rest, that is,
\begin{equation}
v_{0} =0
\end{equation}
and then solve for v, I get
\begin{equation}
v=v_{T}\tan\left(\frac{-gt}{v_{T}}\right)
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
v=\frac{1}{i} v_{ter}\tan\left(\frac{-gt}{v_{ter}} i\right)
\end{equation}
Now this is where I had to whip out some facts about hyperbolic functions. One of those facts was that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{i}\tan( ix) =\tanh( x)
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
v=v_{ter}\tanh\left(\frac{-gt}{v_{ter}}\right)
\end{equation}
And there you have it. That's my solution. It is actually very similar, and differs in the way that I would expect, to the solution to the equation when you treat down as positive. In that case the solution is
\begin{equation}
v=v_{ter}\tanh\left(\frac{gt}{v_{ter}}\right)
\end{equation}
Because of this, it would appear that I did everything right. But, that is really what I am curious about. 
Is what I did correct?
I do not often work with complex numbers, especially in the context of calculus. Therefore, that is my concern. I do not really know if what I did is okay to do. Especially because having a complex speed does not make very much sense to me. But, anyways, I would really appreciate some help with my dilemma.

Comment: Why didn't you change the sign on the drag force? If the object is moving down then the drag force is up, which is now positive in your new formulation. Check your signs before you do a bunch of work :)

Comment: In line with my previous comment, anther thing to point out is that you should thinking about your differential equation before solving it. As you have it, the right hand side of your second equation will always be negative for a real velocity (which you will certainly have). If down is negative, then the velocity of the object as it falls will grow and grow in magnitude without bound, which doesn't make sense with drag. You should have seen red flags before even tackling the problem like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem comes from the sign of the drag term. The first form of the equation you have is not exactly correct. When you say
$$m \dot v = g - c v^2$$
there is an assumption that $v$ is positive, so the negative sign in front of $c v^2$ ensures that the drag for opposes the motion.
Often, sign conventions can get confusing when replacing vectors with scalars, so let's look at the vector form of this equation.
$$m \dot{\vec v} = \vec g - c v^2 \hat v$$
Note that we had to add a $\hat v$ to the drag term to give it a direction, which helps us to see how squaring the $v$ in the scalar equation causes us to lose information about the sign of $v$, which is why the equation only works for positive $v$. In your second equation, you effectively changed the direction of gravity such that it would result in a negative velocity, which means you need to use an equation that works for negative velocities. One option is to simply flip the sign of the drag term, but another, more general, option would be to use an equation that takes the sign of $v$ into account, as below.
$$m \dot v = g - c v |v|$$
This as a more accurate version of your first equation, as it includes the sign information for $v$.

Answer (score 0):

We'll first write out the equation in its "full" form.
\begin{equation}
m\vec{a} =m\vec{g} -cv^{2}\hat{v}
\end{equation}
We will be using the convention that down is negative. We will also be assume we are dealing with two dimensions here. Therefore, we can expand this out as
\begin{equation}
ma_{x}\hat{x} +ma_{y}\hat{y} =-mg\hat{y} -c||\vec{v} ||^{2}\hat{v} =-mg\hat{y} -c||\vec{v} ||||\vec{v} ||\hat{v} =-mg\hat{y} -c||\vec{v} ||\vec{v}
\end{equation}
We know that
\begin{equation}
\vec{v} =v_{x}\hat{x} +v_{y}\hat{y}
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
ma_{x}\hat{x} +ma_{y}\hat{y} =-mg\hat{y} -c||\vec{v} ||v_{x}\hat{x} -c||\vec{v} ||v_{y}\hat{y}
\end{equation}
Now we'll make an assumption that we are only dealing with vertical motion. That is
\begin{equation}
v_{x} =0
\end{equation}
Note that although we have made an assumption about how we are moving, we have not made an assumption about which direction (up or down). That will come later. So we have the following.
\begin{equation}
ma_{y}\hat{y} =-mg\hat{y} -c||\vec{v} ||v_{y}\hat{y}
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
ma_{y} =-mg -c||\vec{v} ||v_{y}
\end{equation}
We know that $\displaystyle ||\vec{v} ||$ is always positive, because it is the magnitude of the velocity vector. In this case, the magnitude will be equal to the speed. To denote this I will use $\displaystyle v^{+}_{y}$. This let's us know that this value will always be positive, while the other $\displaystyle v_{y}$ can still vary.
\begin{equation}
ma_{y} =-mg -cv_{y} v^{+}_{y}
\end{equation}
Now let's try so solve for the terminal speed.
\begin{equation}
v_{y} v^{+}_{y} =-\frac{mg}{c}
\end{equation}
Now here is where we have to make an assumption. We will look at two cases: when $\displaystyle v_{y}$ is positive (the object is moving up) and when $\displaystyle v_{y}$ is negative (the object is moving down). In the case of $\displaystyle v_{y}$ being positive, it will become the same thing as $\displaystyle v^{+}_{y}$ , which is the speed of the object. So we get
\begin{equation}
v^{2} =-\frac{mg}{c}
\end{equation}
Now this is where we have a problem. What this has simply told us is simply that if $\displaystyle v_{y}$ is positive, then the net force on the object cannot be zero.
\begin{equation}
F_{y} \neq 0\ \text{if} \ v_{y}  >0
\end{equation}
Intuitively, this makes sense. If the object is moving up, then gravity and drag will be acting in the same direction. Therefore there is no way for the net force to be zero. Now we look at if $\displaystyle v_{y}$ is negative. If $\displaystyle v_{y}$ is negative, it is the same thing as $\displaystyle -v^{+}_{y}$.And we know that $\displaystyle v^{+}_{y}$ is just the speed. So we get
\begin{equation}
v^{2} =\frac{mg}{c}
\end{equation}
Or
\begin{equation}
v_{ter} =\sqrt{\frac{mg}{c}}
\end{equation}
Now to come back to the differential equation\begin{equation}
ma_{y} =-mg -cv_{y} v^{+}_{y}
\end{equation}
To tackle this, we either use an assumption that we are going up, or we are going down. In the case of going up, we have that\begin{equation}
ma_{y} =-mg -cv^{2}
\end{equation}
In the case of going down we have that\begin{equation}
ma_{y} =-mg +cv^{2}
\end{equation}
Two equations of motion, for two different situations.